# MYSQL GROUP BY/COUNT with condition

Tags: mysql

I wish to extend a simple 'GROUP/COUNT BY' query with a condition that only takes a certain number of rows, according to criteria.

Here is a simple table. A normal 'GROUP BY' would count and return the full quantity of rows, but i'd need to extend my query with the statements seen beside the table:

```
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
| id  | deleted  | status   |  ref  |
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
|   1 |        0 | paid     | 10001 |
|   2 |        0 | paid     | 10001 |
|   3 |        0 | paid     | 10001 |   WHERE status = paid ABD id IN (2,3) //COUNT = 2
|   4 |        0 | paid     | 10002 |
|   5 |        1 | cat      | 10002 |
|   6 |        1 | cat      | 10002 |   WHERE status = cat AND id IN (6) //COUNT = 1
|   7 |        0 | cat      | 10003 |
|  12 |        0 | pending  | 10004 |
|  13 |        1 | pending  | 10005 |
|  14 |        1 | pending  | 10005 |
|  15 |        1 | pending  | 10005 |   WHERE status = pending AND id IN(12,14,17) COUNT = 3
|  16 |        0 | pending  | 10005 |
|  17 |        0 | pending  | 10006 |
|  18 |        0 | pending  | 10006 |
|  19 |        0 | pending  | 10006 |
+-----+----------+----------+-------+
```

What's the simplest way to get the desired results seen below with the conditions outlined above?

```
+----------+---------+
| status   |  COUNT  |
+----------+---------+
| paid     | 2       |
| cat      | 1       |
| pending  | 3       | 
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Update your post with your query and SQL for creation and insertion. Also, the error you get.

Comment: Why isn't pending 5? Am I missing something; you are looking for the non deleted entries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you do a query if you know all the desired rows in advance.
Anyway, a single where-condition `where id IN (2,3,6,12,14,17)` should do the job. So the final query is

```sql
select status, count(*)
from mySimpleTable
where id IN (2,3,6,12,14,17)
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :::

```
select status, count(*) as 'count'
from myTable
where (id IN (2,3) AND status= 'paid') OR
(status = 'cat' AND id IN (6)) OR
(status = 'pending' AND id IN(12,14,17))
group by status
```

Comment: _Try This_ (code-only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.  If you intend to leave this answer on the page and would like to stand the best chance to earn upvotes for your contribution, please edit your answer to include how your answer works and why it is a good solution.  Thank you in advance for helping to make StackOverflow a more valuable resource.